# Asychronous call to wordpress using HTTP callout failing due to timeout

Tags: callout, http

Timeout error with Asychronous HTTP callout to wordpress site
I am trying to make an asynchronous call to a wordpress site using HTTP callout method( using @Future). Everything works on sandbox and I was able to get 60% code coverage after hours of hit and trial methods. The issue started when it was deployed to production box, I am getting timeout error for every call to wordpress. I tried using request.timeout property with values ranging from 2 seconds to 120 seconds. Even then it gives me request time out error 408. My understanding with timeout is it will wait for specified time for a response before terminating with error. Also when it is an asychronous call, there should be no response. Please provide expert opinion on this topic. Below is my code

```
public class Wordpress_AsyncCall {

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void callwordpress(string endp){
        Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endp);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setCompressed(true); // otherwise we hit a limit of 32000

        Http http = new Http();
        try{
        http.send(req);
        }
        catch(System.CalloutException e) {
           System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
           }

   }
```

Comment: If you manually enter a Wordpress URL and then run the code you posted with **exactly** the same URL you get a timeout? Presumably you have setup the "Remote Site" (not that that being missing would normally cause a timeout)?

Comment: The url works well in the browser. I have remote site settings for my destination. When running trial run, I found 1 out 5 message get posted while remaining returns a timeout error.

Comment: So 1 in 5 GET requests to the same URL work or with 5 different URLs only 1 works?

Comment: It is the same URL and success is 1 in 5

Comment: Perhaps the Wordpress site has throttling installed (e.g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) that blocks your requests thinking they are malicious (which is you make them very frequently kinda are).

Comment: This is resolved using JSON API user plugin. Thanks for your help